# Is this a good implementation of Dependency Injection using MVVM without any nuget packages?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-injection, mvvm

So I've been looking into dependency injection for WPF while still using an MVVM pattern.

And something that's been incredibly difficult to wrap my head around was, how to create a navigation service and map it to every ViewModel which needed it.

So without using any nuget packages, this is what I came up with.

In my `App.xaml` I define a few `DataTemplates` and setting the `Views` correspondingly.

```
<Application x:Class="Navs.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Navs"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Navs.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Navs.MVVM.View"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
            <view:HomeView/>
        </DataTemplate>
        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:SettingsViewModel}">
            <view:SettingsView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This will allow controls which has the `DataType` of `X` to display a specific `View`.

And then I went ahead and created my `MainViewModel` which essentially is where I build my "pipeline"

```
using Navs.MVVM.Core;
using Navs.Services;

namespace Navs.MVVM.ViewModel;

public class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private object _currentView;

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get => _currentView;
        set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    /* ViewModels */
    public HomeViewModel HomeViewModel { get; set; }
    public SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel { get; set; }

    /* Commands */
    public RelayCommand SettingsViewCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }

    /* Services */
    public NavService NavService { get; set; }
    public DataService DataService { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        
        HomeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(NavService);
        SettingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel(NavService, DataService);
        
        HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => true, o => { CurrentView = HomeViewModel; });
        SettingsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => true, o => { CurrentView = SettingsViewModel; });
        
        DataService = new DataService();
        NavService = new NavService(this);
        CurrentView = HomeViewModel;
    }
}
```

Doing it this way makes it to where I can register which ever dependencies I want for which ever view model that might need it, by simply passing in the dependency as a property to the corresponding constructor.

```
HomeViewModel = new HomeViewModel(NavService);
SettingsViewModel = new SettingsViewModel(NavService, DataService);
```

And then using the dependencies like so

```
public SettingsViewModel(NavService _navService, DataService dataService)
{
    _dataService = dataService;
    HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => true, o => { _navService.NavigateTo("Home"); });
    FetchDataCommand = new RelayCommand(o => true, o => { Message = _dataService.FetchData(); });
}
```

So the entire `SettingsViewModel` looks like this.

```
public class SettingsViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly DataService _dataService;
    private string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get => _message;
        set
        {
            _message = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand FetchDataCommand { get; set; }
    public SettingsViewModel(NavService _navService, DataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => true, o => { _navService.NavigateTo("Home"); });
        FetchDataCommand = new RelayCommand(o => true, o => { Message = _dataService.FetchData(); });
    }
}
```

And the `NavService` which it utilizes looks like this.

```
public class NavService
{
    private readonly MainViewModel _mainViewModel;
    public NavService(MainViewModel mainViewModel)
    {
        _mainViewModel = mainViewModel;
    }
    public void NavigateTo(string viewName)
    {
        switch (viewName)
        {
            case "Settings":
                _mainViewModel.CurrentView = _mainViewModel.SettingsViewModel;
                break;
            case "Home":
                _mainViewModel.CurrentView = _mainViewModel.HomeViewModel;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I'm utilizing the fact that `CurrentView` is a reference type and is calling `OnPropertyChanged`. Which means that I can set it from any place I want, as long as I have a reference to it which I do through Dependency Injection.

And I feel as if this gives the solution a nice and easy to follow structure. I could wrap the services into a custom `ServiceProvider` and pass that in to the constructor so that I won't have to pass in 50 things if I ever wanted to in the future.

And the `DataService.cs`

```
public class DataService
{
    public string FetchData()
    {
        return "Data from DataService.";
    }
}
```

Is this a good structure? Or should I reconsider the entire solution and use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`? Because looking at example projects using that, it seems as if it just over complicates things and adds way more code, maybe those are just bad examples though?

Here's the `ObservableObject`

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Navs.MVVM.ViewModel;

public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string? propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the `RelayCommand`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Navs.MVVM.Core;

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add => CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        remove => CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: You still haven't really addressed @TobySpeight comment about the title. Tell us what the code does rather than the methodology you are using. Include the using statements at the top of each class. What does the application do? Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778), we want to see enough code to do a good review rather than the minimal amount of code necessary.

Comment: At this point I can't really add anything else, unless I were to source control the solution and share it here. I've explained how everything ties together and I'm curious to know if this is a good way to structure it, would this be a proper use of dependency injection?

Comment: You're passing NavService and DataService to HomeViewModel and SettingsViewModel before actually instantiating those services and so you instantiate your view models with nulls. Are you sure your code is working as is?

Comment: Dependency injection involves a di container which is the thing intended to provide your many dependencies. If you have many dependencies necessary for a given class, you probably gave that class too many responsibilities. Not that you don't pass dependencies down through the layers. You resolve them out the di container when you resolve an instance of a class from it.